# Что означает "Projection" в этом месте документации?

Tags: c#, linq, xamarin, терминология, перевод

Читаю Xamarin Workbook по Linq. И вот не понятное мне место:

> *Sum - **Projection**
>   This sample uses Sum to get the total number of characters of all words in the array.*
>
> ```
> string[] words = { "cherry", "apple", "blueberry" };
> double totalChars = words.Sum(w => w.Length);
> ```

Так как здесь перевести это Projection? Проекция (чего именно?)? Отображение (чего?)?

Не знаю, может, это надо понимать как "*Данная проекция этого массива - это длины его элементов. Мы вычисляем Sum этой проекции, а не исходного массива*"(Примерно то же, что сделать `(from ... where ... select ... ).Sum()`). Пока что это лучшее, что у меня есть.

Может, кто-то понимает это более точно?

Comment: Отображение, см. в Википедии [Функция (математика)](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Функция_(математика)), "Фу́нкция (отображе́ние, опера́тор, преобразова́ние)", и далее по тексту.

Comment: @insolor, т.е. здесь это можно понимать как *Sum от функции*?

Comment: От отображения, раз уж автор использует такой термин. Впрочем, я не знаком с языком Link и принятой для него терминологией.

Comment: Да, все верно: "Проекция". Сумма проекции масссива.